# Do dogs bite more during a full moon?

Tags: zoology, ethology, dogs

> In various cultures throughout the world there is the widespread belief that animals, including companion dogs, are more likely to bite when under the influence of a full moon

http://www.dogexpert.com/full-moon-associated-with-dog-bites/

> IDEAS that the moon inspires insanity in man and beast may be true say researchers who found that animals bite people more often when the moon is full.
>   Doctors at Bradford Royal Infirmary recorded twice the number of animal bites on full moon days.

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1379112/Beware-of-the-dog-during-a-full-moon.html

Seriously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In Australia](http://www.bmj.com/content/321/7276/1561?variant=full-text), at least, they don't:

> ### What is already known on this topic
>
> - Farming folklore holds that dogs bite more at the time of full moons
> - The research literature on the effect of lunar phase on human behaviour has mostly shown no association
>
> ### What this study adds
>
> - In Australia no association exists between lunar phase and dog bites requiring hospital admission

**Barking mad? Another lunatic hypothesis bites the dust**
BMJ 2000; 321 doi: http://dx.doi.org/10.1136/bmj.321.7276.1561 (Published 23 December 2000)